# conversion C# to vb.net issue

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to convert C# to vb.net in WCF, the given below is the line of code

```
 var user = from u in users
               where u.Key == Id
               select u.Value;
```

On using the conversion tool I get the following result

```
Dim user  = _Where u.Key = Id
```

but simultaneously I get an error 'End of statement expected'

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: Read the conversion the wrong way, removed answer

Comment: You're missing part of the query - what conversion tool did you use?

Comment: You can try online translation tool for conversion http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I used converter.telerik.com/ actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about the same using query syntax really:

```
Dim users = From user In users
            Where user.Key = Id
            Select user
```

The `Select` is degenerate and if you would prefer, you could use method syntax instead:

```
users.Where(Function(user) user.Key = ID)
```

Comment: Maybe it's only because it's past my bedtime, but what do you mean by "degenerate"?

Comment: I think `FirstOrDefault` is better practice if using a Key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim user = From u in users Where u.Key = id
           Select u.Value
```

You could also use a lambda.

```
Dim user = users.FirstOrDefault(Function(u)u.Key = id)
```

In the Lambda I used FirstOrDefault as you are using a key. This mean when the first record has been found, no extra time is wasted on searching the rest of the collection. it also means `user` will be `null` if nothing is found. If it was just a `Where` clause you would potentially end up with an empty collection.

Comment: That is VB.NET - the keywords just need to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim user = From u in users 
Where u.Key = Id 
Select u.Value
```

Comment: you don't need the underscores for query syntax ;p